# Is there any way to add new user with a "owner role" (roles/owner) to a google cloud project using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to terrafrom and trying to add a new user to my existing GCP project using terraform.

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "project" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/owner"
    member = "user:abc@gmail.com"
}
```

But it didn't worked at all. Although it was giving me error:

```
Batch "iam-project-test modifyIamPolicy" for request "Create IAM Members 
roles/owner user:abc@gmail.com for \"project \\\"test\\\"\"" returned 
error: Error applying IAM policy for project "test": Error setting IAM policy for
project "test": googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest.
```

Comment: hey @vishalbansal , what's your project id? I guess you are putting your project name not the id

Comment: Great assumption @MethkalKhalawi!!

Comment: If that fixed the issue then it makes sense to close / delete this issue because of simple typography error.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi hey, my project id is correct , i have double checked it.

Answer (score 2):

the issue here is the "roles/owner". Because owner role can be added to a member in your project only through invitation through the [Cloud Console and must explicitly accept the invitation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/setIamPolicy).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the user already inherited the owner role from the organization? It might be related to this: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/4276

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the service account you created for Terraform lacks permissions.

The role `editor` has very broad permissions, but not the permission to modify the roles of others. You need to give this service account the role `resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin` (Project IAM Admin).